# Hystrix's health endpoint not available

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, hystrix

I'm trying to use the Circuit Breaker Pattern with Springboot and Netflix's Hystrix implementation and I'm struggling to access its health endpoint.

The documentation refers it should be available in `/hystrix.stream` but that's not happening. Also, I've noticed the following error upon theapplication initialisation: `Endpoint ID 'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.`.

Does someone know how to solve this issue or how to change the endpoint name?

Versions:

`Springboot 2.1.4.RELEASE`

`Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR1`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see something like this in the logs when the server start:

```
INFO 14451 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar   : Registered '/actuator/hystrix.stream' to hystrix.stream-actuator-endpoint
```

Try /actuator/hystrix.stream

Answer (score 1):

For spring boot 2.1.x , default endpoint URL for hystrix is `/actuator/hystrix.stream`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change spring cloud version to `Hoxton.RELEASE` in `pom.xml`:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```